# Log changes in a vb6 recordset

Tags: logging, vb6, recordset

I have and adodc object with a datagrid to have an editable table in vb6.
I have to store any changes the users makes in the database.

The first idea was to use `Sub grdDataGrid_Click()` to get the row which is being used, but for this, I need to know if any cells has been modified in that row and get the original and new values of it.
Is there a way to check it?
As I saw there are Will and Complete events for recordsets but I never used them before. Are they capable of getting the old and new values of a changed cell?
I also thought about using an trigger (since it can get the old and new data) in oracle on the table I'm using, but in that case I can't get the user who is logged in and did the change.

I'm up for any kind of ideas. It doesn't have to be in vb6 only, I can use stored procedures, functions, triggers if one thing alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the **WillChangeRecord** event. It will tell you why a record(s) is/are changing, and it has a recordset of the records that will change. You can look at Microsoft's documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
Adodc1_WillChangeRecord(ByVal adReason As ADODB.EventReasonEnum, ByVal cRecords As Long, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks promising.
I tried to use it, but I get the error message, any time I do something in this event:
"procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"
I also can't find how to get the value of the record I'm about to update.
I'm sorry but I'm a bit new with adodc events.

Comment: When you put the control onto your form the event declaration is automatically included. Just click on it and put your code inside the procedure. You cannot change the declaration or you will get the error above. To get the values you will need to compare the values in the pRecordset records against the values in your data source.

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted to avoid, to compare recordsets.
I will have about 60 columns with 10.000 rows, I hoped there is a faster way to do it.
Thanks.